# Bukkit MySQL Money System

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to make a money system via mysql. Whenever a player joins the server there profile gets created via mysql and that works perfectly no flaws in that. I'm having trouble making the actual money system support only mysql. Whenever I try to add money to the player it throws out a sql error and breaks that users mysql profile.

I have the following fields in mysql
**UUID, Name, Bits(THE MONEY), Bans**

Here's the error

```
        [14:03:51 INFO]: Crypted lost connection: Disconnected
[14:03:51 ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerQuitEvent to KnoxHub v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:310) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:502) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:487) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerList.disconnect(PlayerList.java:346) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:844) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.NetworkManager.l(NetworkManager.java:314) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ServerConnection.c(ServerConnection.java:145) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:817) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:367) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:657) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:560) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_51]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue SELECT via executeUpdate().
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1621) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1581) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at crypted.knoxhub.Libraries.MySQL.Database.updateSQL(Database.java:132) ~[?:?]
        at crypted.knoxhub.Libraries.Economy.Bits.getBits(Bits.java:37) ~[?:?]
        at crypted.knoxhub.Libraries.Economy.Bits.AddBits(Bits.java:50) ~[?:?]
        at crypted.knoxhub.Hub.Utilities.CreateUser.onJoin(CreateUser.java:41) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        ... 12 more
```

Bits(Money) Class

```
public Bits(Core p, UUID u)
{
    this.u = u;
    this.plugin = p;
    this.MySQL = new PlayerSQL(plugin);
}


public int getBits() throws Exception
{

  int bits2 =  MySQL.sql.updateSQL("SELECT FROM `profiles` WHERE `UUID`= '" + u + "';");

    return bits2;
}

public void setBits( int amount ) throws Exception{

    MySQL.sql.updateSQL("UPDATE FROM `profiles` SET `Bits`= '" + amount + "' WHERE `UUID`='" + u + "'");

}

public void AddBits( int amount ) throws Exception{

    MySQL.sql.updateSQL("UPDATE FROM `profiles` SET `Bits`= '" + getBits() + amount  + "' WHERE `UUID`='" + u + "'");

}

public void TakeBits( int amount ) throws Exception {

    MySQL.sql.updateSQL("UPDATE FROM `profiles` SET `Bits`= '" + getBits() + -amount  + "' WHERE `UUID`='" + u + "'");

}
```

Adding the money on the PlayerQuitEvent

```
    @EventHandler
public void onJoin(PlayerQuitEvent e) throws Exception {
    Player player = e.getPlayer();
    Bits bits = new Bits(plugin, player.getUniqueId());
    bits.AddBits(5000); 
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Debug");

}
```

Comment: You never set the 'u' UUID field in the Bits constructor. You need to add: this.u = u;

Comment: SQL injection issues aside,the sql is passing an object as parameter which happens to be null(UUID) but it should be passing an actual value either way.FROM `profiles` SET `Bits`= '" + amount + "' WHERE `UUID`='" + u.getId() + "'").The bits constructor also never set the UUID object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to set the UUID u field in your Bits class resulting into a nullpointer

```
public Bits(Core p, UUID u)
{
    this.plugin = p;
    this.u = u;
    this.MySQL = new PlayerSQL(plugin);
}
```

If you want to prevent SQLInjection you can use PreparedStatement class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

EDIT:

You've updated the question with an new error and I think the problem is in this method:

```
public int getBits() throws Exception
{

  int bits2 =  MySQL.sql.updateSQL("SELECT FROM `profiles` WHERE `UUID`= '" + u + "';");

    return bits2;
}
```

The updateSQL method is used to run a update query and returns to affected row count.

I think you're aiming for:

```
public int getBits() throws Exception
{

  ResultSet set =  MySQL.sql.executeQuery("SELECT bits FROM `profiles` WHERE `UUID`= '" + u + "';");

  if(set.next())
      return set.getInt("bits");

  return 0;
}
```

I suggest you to read up the bukkit documentation.

Comment: @2Hash Have you tried reading the error message of the error that you got? It says very clearly what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @yole, I read the error message I knew what was happening but I didn't really know how to solve it.

Comment: @2Hash If this solves your problem you should [accept it as the correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/238826)

Comment: @2Hash something important I forgot to mention, make sure to call ResultSet.close() and PreparedStatement.close() (in that order) when you are done reading from the database to release allocated memory. If you don't you eventually run out of memory. I'm not sure how bukkit handles this internally. If bukkit doesn't close it automatically you have to do this manually.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: **Can not issue SELECT via executeUpdate()**.

So, the problem is that you can't use the `SELECT` keyword with `.executeUpdate`. You need to use `.executeQuery`, or in your case, `.execute`. So, your `getBits()` method should look like this

```
public int getBits() throws Exception{

    int bits =  MySQL.sql.execute("SELECT FROM `profiles` WHERE `UUID`= '" + u + "';");

    return bits;
}
```

You should also look into [`PreparedStatements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Although this has nothing to do with the error, taking a user input without using a `PreparedStatement` could result in [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which lets the attacker run any query that they want.

For example, if you took a user input when they gave feedback on a minigame, for example, using the query

```
"INSERT INTO `feedback` (id, userid, feedback) VALUES (NULL, " +  userid + ", " + feedback + ");"
```

The user could simply enter

> 'feedback'"); DROP TABLE `feedback`; --

Which would result in the two statements

> INSERT INTO `feedback` (id, userid, feedback) VALUES (NULL, '*userid*', 'feedback');
>
> DROP TABLE `feedback`